# Lubuntu 19.10 & 20.04: How to tile windows? The window tiling section is missing in lxqt-rc.xml

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys, window-manager, openbox, lxqt

Lubuntu 19.10 and 20.04 (LTS) use Openbox as the window manager.

For Lubuntu 18.04 and 19.04, the file that allowed users to edit various Openbox settings, *lubuntu-rc.xml* and *lxqt-rc.xml*, respectively, has a section titled "Keybindings for window tiling" with keyboard shortcuts for

- HalfLeftScreen
- HalfRightScreen
- HalfUpperScreen and
- HalfLowerScreen

That section is missing in ~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml of Lubuntu 19.10 and 20.04 (LTS).

<s>I followed the instructions in [the release notes](https://lubuntu.me/eoan-released/) to delete</s>

- ~/.config/lxqt/globalkeyshortcuts.conf
- ~/.config/lxqt/lxqt-runner.conf and
- ~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml

and to log out and log back in. However, *lxqt-rc.xml* still doesn't have the window tiling section.

I understand that there have been some conflicts with how the <kbd>Super</kbd> also known as <kbd>Meta</kbd> key conflicted somehow with LXQt. (All the window tiling keyboard shortcuts originally used the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.)

What can users of Lubuntu 19.10 and 20.04 do to get back "window tiling" keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit dated 20220907**: As of [LXQt 0.17.0](https://lxqt-project.org/release/2021/04/16/lxqt-0-17-0#lxqt-session) (April 2021), "Openbox configuration is removed for the sake of WM agnosticism," and `~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml` is no longer recognized, while `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` is.

**Edit dated 20200526**: thanks to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1243734/248158), I realized that another solution would be to change the shortcut for showing/hiding the LXQt menu to something like <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. In other words, if one sets <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to show/hide LXQt's menu, the "pure" <kbd>Super</kbd> is available for use in `~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml`. No need to use the combination of `C+W` detailed below. Your 18.04 `lubuntu-rc.xml` will work now in Lubuntu 20.04 (and 19.10).

---

This answer is applicable to Lubuntu 19.10 and Lubuntu 20.04

And, for clarity, the file used in the Lubuntu session should be `~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml` and that in a pure Openbox session should be named `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`

---

In [How to snap windows?](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-snap-windows/247), a member of the Lubuntu team suggests including some code in *lxqt-rc.xml* to bring back window tiling and also addresses the conflict I mentioned in the question:

> ... in 19.04+, you’ll run into conflicts with lxqt-globalkeys using
> the key to open the menu, so either disable that, reconfigure that, or
> use something other than the Windows key here.

Please look at the keyboard shortcuts section in the [manual for Lubuntu 20.04](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html) which has the list of default keyboard shortcuts but also mentions this:

> Global-keys will take preference over openbox bindings. If a key is used in Global-keys, it will not work in Openbox keyboard shortcuts. For example if the W(indows) key opens the LXQT application menu (equivilant of the windows start menu) in Global-keys, Openbox commands like window resizing (W + arrow keys) will not work correctly. Keep this in mind when using and editing keyboard shortcuts.

---

If one wants the same tiling shortcuts that were used in Lubuntu 19.04, here they are in a somewhat modified form. I've included using the <kbd>Control</kbd> key together with the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and the relevant arrow key instead of just the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and the relevant arrow key.

*One important point with the keyboard shortcuts listed below is that the user must **first** press and hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and then press and hold the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and then press the relevant arrow key before releasing all the keys. If the user first presses the <kbd>Super</kbd> key first, and then presses the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, the shortcuts will not work.*

```
    <!--
        Lubuntu specific.
        Keybindings for window tiling
    -->
    <!--
        # HalfLeftScreen
    -->
  <keybind key="C-W-Left">
    <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
    <action name="MoveResizeTo">
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <height>100%</height>
      <width>50%</width>
    </action>
  </keybind>
    <!--
        # HalfRightScreen
    -->
  <keybind key="C-W-Right">
    <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
    <action name="MoveResizeTo">
      <x>-0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <height>100%</height>
      <width>50%</width>
    </action>
  </keybind>
    <!--
        # HalfUpperScreen
    -->
  <keybind key="C-W-Up">
    <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
    <action name="MoveResizeTo">
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>100%</width>
      <height>50%</height>
    </action>
  </keybind>
    <!--
        # HalfLowerScreen
    -->
  <keybind key="C-W-Down">
    <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
    <action name="MoveResizeTo">
      <x>0</x>
      <y>-0</y>
      <width>100%</width>
      <height>50%</height>
    </action>
  </keybind>
```

After the edits, open a terminal and run `openbox --reconfigure` for the keybinding to take effect. Alternatively, log out and log back in.

---

I didn't include keyboard shortcuts for maximizing or minimizing windows because these actions and many others can easily be accessed by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>. Note that Openbox prefers to use *iconify* instead of *minimize*.

Comment: Thanks! These are not really Lubuntu-specific. I made another set for the keypad so I could place them in the 4 corners and middle.

Answer (score 3):

DK Bose's answer is great.

In general, only two steps are involved:

1. Disable the "Super_L" entry in your Global Actions Manager(GAM).
2. Add entry in Openbox `lxqt-rc.xml` config.

### Disable `Super_L`.

Search for "Shortcut Keys".

Look for `Super_L` entry and disable it
[image]

### Configure Openbox keyboard binding.

Nice keyboard binding entry is found here in [openbox documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Openbox#Window_snapping), they call it as "Window Snapping":

```
<keybind key="W-Left">
    <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
    <action name="MaximizeVert"/>
    <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <width>50%</width>
    </action>
    <action name="MoveToEdge"><direction>west</direction></action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-Right">
    <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
    <action name="MaximizeVert"/>
    <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <width>50%</width>
    </action>
    <action name="MoveToEdge"><direction>east</direction></action>
</keybind>
```

Then reconfigure Openbox by running `openbox --reconfigure`.

Answer (score 1):

Nice solution above. :-)

In the mean time I wrote a script to do the same. You can hook it to lxqt shortcuts - meta+left, etc.:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# -x

offset_lubuntu_panel=50
width=$(wmctrl -d |head -n1 | cut -f5 -d' '|cut -dx -f1) # size of your monitor, say 1600x900
height=$(( $(wmctrl -d |head -n1 | cut -f5 -d' '|cut -dx -f2) - offset_lubuntu_panel))
width_half=$((width/2))
height_half=$((height/2))

case $1 in
    left)
        wmctrl -r :ACTIVE:  -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz # un-maximizing an active window:
        sleep .1
        wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,$width_half,$height # left half
        ;;
    right) 
        wmctrl -r :ACTIVE:  -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz # un-maximizing an active window:
        sleep .1
        wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,$width_half,0,$width_half,$height # right half
        ;;
    up)
        wmctrl -r :ACTIVE:  -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz # un-maximizing an active window:
        sleep .1
        wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,$width,$height_half # upper half
        ;;
    down)
        wmctrl -r :ACTIVE:  -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz # un-maximizing an active window:
        sleep .1
        wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,$height_half,$width,$height_half # lower half
        ;;
    max)
        wmctrl -r :ACTIVE:  -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz # maximizing the current  window
        ;;
    *)
        echo -e "\t$(basename $0) [left|right|up|down|max]"
            echo -e "\t\twmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,$width,$heightpulka  # gravity,x,y,w,h"
            echo -e "\tRun: lxqt-config-globalkeyshortcuts to add shortcuts to your system"
            echo -e "\tor edit manually this file: ~/.config/lxqt/globalkeyshortcuts.conf"
        echo
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you, this is probably the most portable implementation yet!
I addeded it to the repo I keep for initiating new machines :)

Comment: Oh, gee. It is a big honor for me, humble amateur. :-)  Thank YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Your answers helped me to be able to use window tiling with Lubuntu 22.04 and LXQt 0.17.0.
I just added also four screens in the four corners, a max screen and a mid screen to DK Bose's Code.

```
<!--
    Lubuntu specific.
    Keybindings for window tiling
-->
<!--
    # HalfLeftScreen
-->
<keybind key="C-W-Left">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <height>100%</height>
    <width>50%</width>
  </action>
</keybind>
<!--
    # HalfRightScreen
-->
<keybind key="C-W-Right">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>-0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <height>100%</height>
    <width>50%</width>
  </action>
</keybind>
<!--
    # HalfUpperScreen
-->
<keybind key="C-W-Up">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>100%</width>
    <height>50%</height>
  </action>
</keybind>
<!--
    # HalfLowerScreen
-->
<keybind key="C-W-Down">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>0</x>
    <y>-0</y>
    <width>100%</width>
    <height>50%</height>
  </action>
</keybind>
<!--
    # UpperLeftScreen
-->
<keybind key="C-W-A-Prior">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <height>50%</height>
    <width>50%</width>
  </action>
</keybind>
<!--
    # UpperRightScreen
-->
<keybind key="C-W-A-Next">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>-0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <height>50%</height>
    <width>50%</width>
  </action>
</keybind>
<!--
    # LowerLeftScreen
-->
<keybind key="C-W-A-Left">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>0</x>
    <y>-0</y>
    <width>50%</width>
    <height>50%</height>
  </action>
</keybind>
<!--
    # LowerRightScreen
-->
<keybind key="C-W-A-Right">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>-0</x>
    <y>-0</y>
    <width>50%</width>
    <height>50%</height>
  </action>
</keybind>
<!--
    # MaxScreen
-->
<keybind key="C-W-A-Up">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>100%</width>
    <height>100%</height>
  </action>
</keybind>
<!--
    # MidScreen
-->
<keybind key="C-W-A-Down">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>25%</x>
    <y>25%</y>
    <width>50%</width>
    <height>50%</height>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Comment: This is not an answer it is a thank you comment.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1294801)

Comment: Ok thank you and sorry. I'm new here and I try to move it as a comment to DK Bose's Code.

Comment: Oh, I have to less reputation for a comment. Should I delete the whole answer instead? For me this corner screens are helpful and I do not have the knowledge if this is to simple to post.