# Disable Keyboard Shortcut key Super + num on lubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04

I've just switched to using Lubuntu 19.04 and I am having problems getting keyboard shortcuts working how I like. I have assigned <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to switch desktops. However the new setting doesn't take effect. There is some other behaviour overriding my settings which causes <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to cycle between application groups. I can't find the settings to change this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the <kbd>Super</kbd> key as the sole modifier key. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>. So, in your case, use something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc to switch desktops.

The reason seems to be that in Lubuntu 19.04, the <kbd>Super</kbd> key is used by LXQt differently than in previous Lubuntu versions.

> ... but in 19.04+, you’ll run into conflicts with lxqt-globalkeys using
>   the key to open the menu, so either disable that, reconfigure that, or
>   use something other than the Windows key here.

Source: https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-snap-windows/247/4

---

If you're interested in window snapping, see [Lubuntu 19.10: How to tile windows? The window tiling section is missing in lxqt-rc.xml](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182097/lubuntu-19-10-how-to-tile-windows-the-window-tiling-section-is-missing-in-lxqt).

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm not sure if this is exactly the same issue. I switched to cinnamon desktop and removed lxqt, but the problem persists. For now I am using Super+Fn instead, but I would still like to figure out what is hogging Super+n and how I can control that.