# How to make Openbox to use my custom config file?

Tags: lubuntu, window-manager, openbox, shortcut-keys

I'd like to use several custom keybindings to handle windows more effectively. So I copied the `rc.xml` from `/etc/xdg/openbox/` to `~/.config/openbox/` and edited the relevant (`<keyboard>`) section of the copy. In order to see how it works, I added the following simplest fragment:

```
<keybind key="W-Up">
    <action name="Maximize"/>
</keybind>
```

What do I do next? I have tried `«openbox --reconfigure»`, `«openbox --configure ~/.config/openbox/rc.xml»`, `«openbox --replace»`, even combinations of these parameters to no avail (rebooting did not help either).

P. S. I use Lubuntu 20.04 x64.

Comment: Lubuntu 20.04 uses LXQt. At login time, do you use the Lubuntu session or the Openbox session? In the Lubuntu or LXQt sessions, the `W` key aka the `Super` key aka the `Meta` key cannot be used the way you intend. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182097/lubuntu-19-10-20-04-how-to-tile-windows-the-window-tiling-section-is-missing for why. In short, `C+W+Up` will work but `W+Up` won't.

Comment: @guiverc I see, thank you!

Comment: @DKBose I have read the post you are referring to (btw, thank for the analysis and detailed answer). I copied the code for the actions triggred by `C-W-Up`, modified `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` and run `openbox --reconfigure`. Hitting `Ctrl-Win-Up` (I took into account your comment about the order of keys pressing) still has no any visible effect.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but did you rename your file to `lxqt-rc.xml` from just `rc.xml`? That step is important.

Comment: @DKBose Also, I modified '~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml' with the same piece of code and performed «reconfiguration». Still no luck.

Comment: Essentially, I copied both these files from `/etc/xdg/openbox/` and modified each of them.

Comment: When you run `openbox --reconfigure` is there any response in the terminal?

Comment: Nope. No any output.

Comment: Then I suggest you post your `~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml` as a pastebin link for us to look at.

Comment: @DKBose Sorry for the delay. [Here](https://pastebin.com/YZ3mYz2X) we are. The only change I did to this file was insertion of lines №№ 189-197.

Comment: Okay, please give me some time to look at it.

Comment: What you uploaded has just `W-Up`, `W-Down`, etc instead of `C-W-Up`, `C-W-Down`, etc.

Comment: @DKBose I am not quite sure I understand what you mean. Take a look at the line № 189. It is ` <keybind key="C-W-Up">`.`

Comment: But see lines 329-331! Also, put your code after the `ChainQuit` stanza, not before it.

Comment: @DKBose Yes, that works! I moved the block to the very end of the section, just before `</keyboard>` and that was it. Were it an answer, in stead of comment, I would be glad to accept it. As it is now, I can only say that I appreciate your helping. I'll update my original question in stead.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The solution was found. The credit for it goes entirely to @DK Bose. Here are three items that sum up our lengthy exchange of comments:

1. the file to edit is `~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml` (if it does not
   exist, it should be copied from `/etc/xdg/openbox`)
2. hotkeys like `Win-Left`, `Win-Up` and so on do not work in LXQt (see
   [the Lubuntu manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html)); one should stick with alternatives, for
   example, `Ctrl-Win-Left` and the likes or some thing else;
3. the xml blocks for specific bindings should not be the first lines
   after the opening `<keyboard>` tag (it is failproof to put them at the
   end of the keyboard binding section, i. e. right before
   `</keyboard>`).

Answer (score 0):

> hotkeys like Win-Left, Win-Up and so on do not work in LXQt (see the Lubuntu manual);

That's not true. W-Left and W-Up work, if in the LXQt-Settings in the Shortcut Keys "Show/hide main menu" is deactivated, or "Show/hide main menu" is set to something else than W, like for example W+Y.