# How do I rebind the keyboard shortcut to open the menu in Lubuntu 20.04?

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys, lxqt

All the answers I've been able to find are for LXDE but I need the answer for LXQT.

What command/DBus message opens the main menu? Clicking the existing entry in the Shortcut Keys utility only lets me enable/disable it, not modify the shortcut or see what command it runs.

Is there a way to see what command the existing entry runs? The documentation doesn't seem to have a configuration file location.

Comment: So you don't want the default `Super` key to open LXQt's menu? You want to set it to something else?

Comment: I could change it to `Meta+Space` through the GUI. What difficulty are you facing?

Comment: Looks like it is that simple. Fro some reason I thought that since I can't edit the command, I can't change the shortcut key either. Just curious though, what is the command that gets executed by this binding?

Comment: I'll see if I can dig that out for you.

Comment: Hmmm...  look in `~/.config/lxqt/globalkeyshortcuts.conf` for `path=/panel/mainmenu/show_hide` and look in `/usr/share/lxqt/lxqt-panel/mainmenu.desktop` which has `Type=Service` and `ServiceTypes=LXQtPanel/Plugin`. Neither indicate a conventional command! Sorry I can't help more but I'll pass on your query to [guiverc](https://askubuntu.com/users/469152/guiverc) who is part of the Lubuntu team.

Comment: The `lxqt-globalkeysd` is the LXQt (inc. Lubuntu) way of handling them, however to get a 'pure' LXQt view of what upstream intends you should login using the "LXQt" session, Lubuntu adds complexity with our use of `openbox` (which involve minor changes). I've watched this question, but haven't been able to provide much (except wanting to add links to our manual pages..). You can often see more by searching using "site:*.lubuntu.me" so as to include our phabricator instance (though *shorthand* can hide some detail). I suspect in this case @DKBose knows more than I do though (I'm not a *dev*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Lubuntu 20.04, pressing the <kbd>Super_L</kbd> key, aka the left Meta or Windows key, launches the LXQt menu.

To change that, use Menu > Preferences > LXQt Settings > Shortcut Keys.

In the GUI that opens,

[image: GUI for changing shortcuts in LXQt]

scroll to the item having the description Show/hide main menu. Select that line by left-clicking on it and then click on *Modify* near the top right.

Click in the box Shortcut box showing `Super_L` and type your preference. Then OK and close the GUI. You're done.

Answer (score 1):

The answer does not allow you to change it to another modifier, though - the original binding is "special" as it is not possible to enter that in the UI.  However one can use xmodmap to make any key into the Super_L key.  For example, I have swapped the "Search" key (which acts as Super on my Chromebook) with the right Control key, so that I get Search acting as Control and the right Control key acting as the menu key.

There is no need to mess with window manager configurations, as this is simply a job for xmodmap.  On lubuntu 21.10, I am able to do the following:

Create `.config/autostart/xmodmap-autostart.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=xmodmap autostart
Exec=xmodmap $HOME/.config/xmodmap
Name=xmodmap-autostart
OnlyShowIn=LXQt
Type=Application
Version=1.0
```

and create `.config/xmodmap`

```
remove control = Control_R
remove mod4 = Super_L
keycode 133 = Control_R
keycode 105 = NoSymbol
add control = Control_R
keycode 105 = Super_L
add mod4 = Super_L
```

The trick is using NoSymbol as I am trying to swap right control with the super key, but you can't do it all at once.