# Is it possible to sync my todos from the To do Gnome app with my Ubuntu One account?

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-one

I've discovered the "To Do" application on my new install of 20.04 and I've created an Ubuntu One account and so I'm wondering if it is possible to sync my todo list between my laptop and my desktop? There doesn't seem to be a way to sync my todos through the application itself. Does it do it automatically?

Comment: Ubuntu ONE cloud storage shutdown some time ago (http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/) and it's primary purpose now is SSO logins (I use it to login to this site for example)

Comment: Thanks. If you post that as the answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu ONE cloud storage shutdown some time ago, and it's primary purpose now is SSO logins (I use it to login to this site for example)

http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/

Comment: Please see if you can help out here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1243734/248158 Thanks!