# Lubuntu 20.04 - Super+Left shortcut is not functional where other direction work

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys, 20.04

I've went through this interesting thread: Lubuntu 19.10 & 20.04: How to tile windows? The window tiling section is missing in lxqt-rc.xml [Lubuntu 19.10 & 20.04: How to tile windows? The window tiling section is missing in lxqt-rc.xml](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182097/lubuntu-19-10-20-04-how-to-tile-windows-the-window-tiling-section-is-missing).

It works perfectly for `Super+Right` / `Super+Up` / `Super+Down`, but is not functionnal for `Super+Left`. Note that the command `openbox --reconfigure` does not change the situation.

Here is the extract of `lxqt-rc.xml`. Does anybody have an idea why `Super+Left` is not functionnal ?

```
    <keybind key="W-Left">
        <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
        <action name="MaximizeVert"/>
        <action name="MoveResizeTo">
            <width>50%</width>
        </action>
        <action name="MoveToEdge"><direction>west</direction></action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-Right">
        <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
        <action name="MaximizeVert"/>
        <action name="MoveResizeTo">
            <width>50%</width>
        </action>
        <action name="MoveToEdge"><direction>east</direction></action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-Down">
       <action name="Unmaximize"/>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-Up">
       <action name="Maximize"/>
    </keybind>
```

Comment: Where did you get your code from? It is not the code in the linked Q&A.

Comment: I went through *dozen* of websites. I tried the above code from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245776/lubuntu-20-04-superleft-shortcut-is-not-functional-where-other-direction-work.

Comment: oops, here is the link with the code: https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-snap-windows/247 (hope this is correct to post a link out of SO ?)

Comment: The Super+Left combo in that code works for me. I don't know why it isn't working for you. Sorry!

Comment: I've noticed stange behavious. 1s point: all the shortcuts were disabled after a reboot, the later `open --reconfigure` command did not bring them back. 2nd point: I've changer the key to add control (e.g. `C-W-Left`). The shortcut `C-W-Right` was not functionnal !! Is there any additionnal shortcut application that is taking over openbox ?

Comment: Which version of Lubuntu are you on? Is this an upgrade from an earlier version? Perhaps try asking at https://discourse.lubuntu.me/ where the Lubuntu devs are present. Maybe they can guide you.

Comment: I'm running v20.04. I will go to this website. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've posted on discourse.ubuntu.me, and finally found the answer :
https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-resize-windows-using-hot-keys-to-fill-50-of-the-screen/1189 :

> The instruction `<keybind key="W-Right">` was not working. I had to use `<keybind key="Super-Right">` instead. In my first message, I was mixing `Super` and `W`. For some reason, the 2 keys are not the same.